# onActivityResult not being called from fragment on device, but works fine on emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onactivityresult

Went to run the app on my device and it isn't functioning as it was on the emulator.
The pages are stored as fragments and switched out with a bottom navigation bar.

```
public class HomeController extends FragmentActivity implements Serializable {
    private BottomNavigationViewEx navBar;
    private Fragment selectedFragment;
    private HomeFragment homeActivity;
    private OverviewFragment overviewActivity;
    private UploadFragment uploadActivity;
    private ProfileFragment profileActivity;
    private SettingsFragment settingsActivity;

    // Called when the page is created.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        // Setup the onclick listener for the bottom
        navBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                boolean upload = false;
                // Check if the same tab is not clicked twice.
                if(item.getItemId() != lastNumber){
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = homeActivity;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_overrview:
                            selectedFragment = overviewActivity;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_upload:
                            selectedFragment = uploadActivity;
                            upload = true;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_profile:
                            selectedFragment = profileActivity;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_settings:
                            selectedFragment = settingsActivity;
                            break;
                    }
                    // Set the fragment holder as the selected fragment.
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    // Work out what animation to use for the fragment transition.
                    if(upload){
                        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
                    }else{
                        if((item.getItemId() < lastNumber) && !firstTime){
                            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_right_enter, R.anim.push_right_exit);
                        }else{
                            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_enter, R.anim.push_left_exit);
                        }
                        firstTime = false;
                    }
                    lastNumber = item.getItemId();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, homeActivity);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

and then the fragment that is calling the file picker intent.

```
public class UploadFragment extends Fragment {
    private void selectFile(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Check if the data selected is valid.
            if(data != null){
                copyFileForUpload(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

When running on the emulator it works perfectly and returns back to the correct fragment and calls the onActivityResult. When i put it on my device only the onActivityResult from the home controller is called and the fragment is changed back to the HomeFragment(default).

I have tried:

- getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
- getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);

As i saw a few other posts suggested.

edit: i have also made sure i was running the same version of android on both the emulator and device. The problem still persists.

edit2: just tried on another device pixelXL and it works fine, it just doesnt work on my Samsung s8. Could be the api level difference s8 = level 24 and pixel = 27?

Any help would be great! 
Thanks!

Comment: Please check onActivityResult() at the activity level and route to fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Please add onActivityResult() method in Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(upload)
    selectedFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Just tried, it seems selectedFragment is being deleted when returning from the activity. So when i try to invoke onActivityResult i get ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Comment: just found this in the log, this is printed when the gallery picker activity is finished: FragmentActivity: Activity result no fragment exists for who: android:fragment:1

Answer (score 1):

```
  In the parent Activity class, override the onActivityResult() method and even override the same in the Fragment class and call as the following code.

In the parent class:

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dualPane);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

In the child class:

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // In fragment class callback
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this still hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: the solution is to just use startActivityForResult instead of getActivity().start...? Because as far as I can see, you are overriding the definition of onActivityResult with its own definition, in the Activity (i.e. this behaves exactly the same as if the override in the answer did not exist)